# Creating a tactic for 'destructing' a list by last element?

Tags: coq, tactic, list-manipulation

Sometimes, I have a context in which I have some `l : list X`, and I want to prove the goal by proving that (1) If `l = []`, the goal holds, and (2) If `l = l' ++ [x]`, the goal still holds.

This usually takes the form of a proof pattern. For example,

```ml
Goal forall {X} (l : list X), True.
  Proof.
    intros.
    destruct (unsnoc l) as [ [l' x] | ] eqn:E.
    2 : {
      rewrite unsnoc_None in E. subst l. 
      (* now all instances of l have been replaced with []*)
      
      exact I.
    } {
      rewrite unsnoc_Some in E.
      (* now we have l = l' ++ [x] *)

      exact I.
    }
  Qed.
```

How can I write a tactic `unsnoc_destruct l as [ E l' x]` which does generate this proof structure for me?

I tried the following, but it has the wrong order of goals, and I cannot seem to suggest better variable names using an as clause.

```ml
Ltac unsnoc_destruct l :=
  let E := fresh "E" l in
  let x := fresh "x" in
  let l' := fresh "l'" in
  destruct (unsnoc l) as [ [x l'] | ] eqn:E;
  [ 
    rewrite -> unsnoc_Some in E
  | rewrite unsnoc_None in E; subst l ].
```

---

Including definitions and proofs used in the question above:

```ml
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint unsnoc {X : Type} (l : list X) : option (list X * X) :=
   match l with
   | [] => None
   | x :: l' => match unsnoc l' with
     | None => Some ([], x)
     | Some (l'', x') => Some (x :: l'', x')
     end
   end.
 
 Lemma last_inversion {A : Type} : forall (x y : A) xs ys,
     xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> xs = ys /\ x = y.
 Proof.
   intros. apply (f_equal (@rev A)) in H.
   repeat rewrite (rev_app_distr) in H.
   simpl in H. inversion H. apply (f_equal (@rev A)) in H2.
   repeat rewrite rev_involutive in H2.
   auto.
 Qed.
 
 Lemma unsnoc_spec {X : Type} : forall (l : list X) (l' : list X),
   (forall x, unsnoc l = Some (l', x) <-> l = l' ++ [x])
   /\ (unsnoc l = None <-> l = []).
 Proof.
   induction l.
   - simpl. intros. repeat split. try discriminate.
     intros. destruct l'; discriminate.
   - destruct (unsnoc l) eqn:E.
     + destruct p as [l1 x1].
       intros. split.
       * intros. simpl. rewrite E. 
         specialize (IHl l1).
         destruct IHl as [IHl1 IHl2].
         specialize (IHl1 x1).
         assert (l = l1 ++ [x1]) as H. {
           apply IHl1. auto.
         }
         rewrite H. 
         split. intros.
         ** inversion H0.  auto. 
         ** intros. 
            replace (a :: l1 ++ [x1]) with ((a :: l1) ++ [x1]) in H0 by auto.
            apply last_inversion in H0. destruct H0. subst. auto.
       * intros. split; [ | discriminate].
         simpl. rewrite E. intros. inversion H.
     + simpl.
        assert (l = []) as H. {
         specialize (IHl []) as [IHl1 IHl2].
         apply IHl2. auto.
        }
        subst l. simpl.
        repeat split; try discriminate.
        * intros. inversion H. subst. reflexivity.
        * intros. 
          replace ([a]) with ([] ++ [a]) in H by auto.
          apply last_inversion in H. destruct H. subst. auto.
 Qed.
 
 Lemma unsnoc_Some {X : Type} : forall (l : list X) (l' : list X) (x : X),
   (unsnoc l = Some (l', x) <-> l = l' ++ [x]).
 Proof.
   intros. apply unsnoc_spec.
 Qed.
 
 Lemma unsnoc_None {X : Type} : forall (l : list X),
   (unsnoc l = None <-> l = []).
 Proof.
   intros. apply unsnoc_spec. exact [].
 Qed.
```

Answer (score 4):

A fun way is to express the destructuring as something resembling an induction principle. For example, you can define "snoc induction" like this:

```
From Coq Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition snoc {A:Type} (xh : list A) (x : A) : list A := xh ++ [x].

Lemma list_snoc_ind {A:Type} (P : list A -> Prop) :
  P [] ->
  (forall xh x, P xh -> P (snoc xh x)) ->
  forall l, P l.
Proof.
  intros Pnil Psnoc l.
  rewrite <- rev_involutive.
  induction (rev l) as [|xh xr IH]. 1: easy.
  now apply Psnoc.
Qed.

Lemma list_snoc_destruct {A:Type} (P : list A -> Prop) :
  P [] ->
  (forall xh x, P (snoc xh x)) ->
  forall l, P l.
Proof. intros Pnil Psnoc. eapply list_snoc_ind; easy. Qed.
```

If you leave out the inductive hypothesis, you get a "destruction scheme," like `list_snoc_destruct`.

The induction tactic now allows you to use this instead of the default induction scheme. In general, `induction .. using scheme` allows you to use `scheme`, as long as `scheme` looks "close enough" to an induction principle.

This then allows you to do the match like in this example:

```
Goal forall A (l:list A), l = nil \/ exists hd tl, l = snoc hd tl.
Proof.
  intros A la.
  induction la as [|xh x] using list_snoc_destruct.
  - now left.
  - right. do 2 eexists. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, writing `induction` in a `destruct`ion based proof feels rather odd to me

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay there is also `elim`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that feels more like `destruct` than induction:

```
Ltac _unsnoc_destruct l x l':=
  let x := fresh x in
  let l' := fresh l' in
  (destruct (unsnoc_dest l) as [[x [l']]|]) ; subst l.

Tactic Notation "unsnoc_destruct" constr(l) "as" ident(x) ident(l') := _unsnoc_destruct l x l'.

Variable (P : forall {X}, list X -> Prop).

Goal forall X (l : list X), P l.
Proof.
  intros X l.
  unsnoc_destruct l as x l'.
  (* 2 Goals: P (l' ++ [x]) and P [] *) 
  Undo.
  unsnoc_destruct l as y z.
  (* 2 Goals: P (y ++ [z]) and P [] *)
```

Note the use of `Tactic Notation` to wrap the tactic, that itself handles the naming. Ultimately, the core tactic is a one-liner `(destruct (unsnoc_dest l) as [[x [l']]|]) ; subst.`, so you might even just use that – although it is probably less readable.

(On a side-note, the quantification on `l'` outside of the conjunct in your statement of `unsnoc_spec` is strange.)

Comment: The `subst` could be a `subst l` so that the tactic does not substitute other equalities that the user might have wanted to keep.